# how to update top.links and other magento blocks without refresh page

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, ajax, jquery, toplinks

how can we update value of mycart on top.links with out refresh magento page on add to cart event

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#product-addtocart-button').click(function()
        {
            var formurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add') ?>";
            var datafile=$("#product_addtocart_form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : datafile,
                url  : formurl,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                    //need code to update My cart on click event 
                }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Edit Controller (checkout/cart/)

```
public function toplinkAction()
{
  echo $count = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
}
```

And Edit javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#product-addtocart-button').click(function()
        {
            var formurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add') ?>";
            var datafile=$("#product_addtocart_form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : datafile,
                url  : formurl,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                   var formurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/toplink') ?>";
                    $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : datafile,
                url  : formurl,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                    var responseText= Math.round(responseText)
                    document.getElementsByClassName("top-link-cart")[0].innerHTML = "My Cart ("+responseText+"&nbsp;item(s))";
                }
                });
            return false;
                }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom  controller and   call another ajax request on  addtocart success response

return  toplink content on content on

just like

```
public function ajaxtoplinkAction()
{
    $result = array();
     $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('topLinks')->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

jaavscript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#product-addtocart-button').click(function()
        {
            var formurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add') ?>";
            var datafile=$("#product_addtocart_form").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : datafile,
                url  : formurl,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                    //need code to update My cart on click event 
            gettoplink(); // call this funtion
                }
                });
            return false;
        });

    function gettoplink(){
        var ajxformurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('yourmodulename/yourcontrollername/ajaxtoplink') ?>";
    new Ajax.Request(ajxformurl, {
      onSuccess: function(response) {
            var transport=response.responseText.evalJSON(true); 
            var toplinkcontent=transport.content

            }
    });

}

    });
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: not working
**
 $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                data : {},
                url  : formurl,
                success: function(responseText)
                {
                    alert("sad");
                }
                });**

Comment: pleas ccheck........................

Comment: not working new Ajax.Request

function gettoplink(){
            var formurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/ajaxtoplink') ?>";
                alert("Working Here");
                new Ajax.Request(ajxformurl,{
alert("Not working here");
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                var transport=response.responseText.evalJSON(true); 
                var toplinkcontent=transport.content

            }
                });

Comment: focus on alert ...............

Comment: have you create new action ajaxtoplink at cart controller ?

Comment: yes at location code/core/mage/checkout/cart/ ...........

public function ajaxtoplinkAction()
    {
        $result = array();
        $result['content'] = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('topLinks')->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        echo $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }

Comment: use $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template_links')->toHtml(); instead of $this->getLayout()->getBlock('topLinks')->toHtml();